# how to append an array to a bigger array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

EDIT: Sorry, lemme try to add some clarification. 
I have a python code:

```
E1 = [1,2,3,4]
E2 = [2,3,4,5]
#E3 = [...] and so on

arraylist = []

for i in range(1,acq+1):
    dat = "E{}".format(i)
    arraylist.append(dat)

E_total  = np.add.reduce([arraylist])
```

I want to append previously defined arrays E1, E2, E3... into arraylist, such that print(arraylist) would return [E1, E2, E3, ....]

Right now when I print array list it looks like ["E1", "E2", "E3"]. 
When I try to sum the arrays to solve E_total I get an error because E1 isn't calling my array E1 = [1,2,3,4] it is calling the string "E1" which has no definition.

**I want to have arraylist = [E1,E2,E3,...] and not append the strings "E1" "E2"...**

**When I print(arraylist[0]) it returns E1, I would like it to return [1,2,3,4] as that is what E1 is defined as.**

Can I do this without a dictionary? I don't want to define "E1":E1 , "E2":E2 and so on. That seems very bulky and not feasible for many E's.

**update**
Typing by hand :

```
arraylist = [E1,E2,E3,...] 
sums = np.add.reduce([arraylist])
```

Works!
 I think the problem is that I am appending the string "E1" to arraylist with the forloop and not E1. How can I use .append such that I can append E1 rather than string "E1"

Here is how I get the E_n arrays:

```
A1 = glob.glob('/media...) 
A1.sort() 
B1 =[] 
for elem in A1: 
  B1.append(float((elem.split('_'))[3]))
C1 = [] 
for elem in A1: 
C1.append(np.sum(np.genfromtxt(elem)))
E1 = np.gradient(C1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use dictionary `d = {"E1":  123, "E2": 987}` - and then you can use strings to get value - `d["E1"] + d["E2"]`

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I want  arraylist = [E1,E2,E3,...] 
but right now I used a forloop to fill it with the string "E1" "E2" and so on.  I dont want to use a dictionary because that means I would have to set each "E1" to the vector E1 and so on.for example:  E1 = [1,2,3,4].

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Please provide more details.

Comment: I want to make an arraycalled arraylist such that arraylist = [E1,E2,E3,...]. The way I am doing this with the forloop makes arraylist = ["E1","E2","E3"...] and I cannot use np.add on strings. E1,E2,E3 have all been previously defined.

Comment: Are you trying to make a multidimensional list? **This still isn't clear**.

Comment: yes I want it multidimensional such that when i use np.shape i get (A,B) where A is the number of "acq" and B is the the number of elements in the E arrays. The answer I got does this, but as mentioned:  not the best way to go about it.

Comment: @Sav What you have in your example are Python lists, not NumPy ndarrays! Is this dummy data, what does your actual program look like? Where does the data even come from?

Comment: In response to your comment on the rest of the program: How are you reading the files and creating the arrays?

Comment: Can you put some print statements at regular intervals, so that we can see the contents of those variables? What are `B1` and `E1,` for example? What does the data in the files look like? See: [mcve].

Comment: You show `E1`.. Is E2` the same thing but with different names?  Why different names?  Normally in python we collect things in lists, not by names `e1,e2,e3,...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will create the arraylist you want, but I would seriously reconsider thinking how your input data is organized (use a dict with keys of the sequence number that map to your arrays or somesuch).

```
E1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
E2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
E3 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

arraylist = []
acq = 3
temp = []
for i in range(acq):
    exec_str = "temp = E{}".format(i+1)
    exec(exec_str)
    arraylist.append(temp)

print(arraylist)
```

This prints:
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

Edit: Given your updated information I would structure my input loop something like this.  This code won't be entirely correct (I don't know what your input data looks like or the filenames), but should give you an idea of how you should loop over this data (you will avoid the entire issue with weird dynamically named arrays and also not need to build all those weird intermediate lists and whatnot).

```
input_files = glob.glob('/media*') #or whatever the search is

number_of_cols = 4 # set this to whatever value it will be in the real data, should equal the length of your eventual gradient

E = np.empty([len(input_files), number_of_cols])

for input_file in input_files.sort():
    split_name = input_file.split('_')
    # Save this in an array B here if you want to
    index_val = split_name[3]-1 # Your file numbers seem to start at 1, while arrays are 0 indexed.
    # Save this into an array C if you want to
    summed_val = np.sum(np.genfromtxt(input_file))

    input_grad = np.gradient(summed_val)
    E[index_val] = input_grad
```

Note that I might be handling the indexing wrong here (I'm not sure what your filenames look like).  Consider just using

```
for i, input_file in enumerate(input_files):
   ....
   E[i] = input_grad
```

if the order of the rows in E doesn't matter to you.

Comment: Yeah, depending on how you load in the values arrays, you could also create a 2d numpy array from the start and call np.add.reduce on that directly (no need for the arraylist creation or extra loop).

Comment: @Sav This isn't the best route to go at all, they even wrote _I would seriously reconsider thinking how your input data is organized_.

Comment: @AMC I see that. I was just apprehensive about using a dictionary since I hadn't before and am much more comfortable just using simple np.arrays.  Since 3 commenters are saying to use a dictionary I will rewrite it. It is good to know that I can force it to work with exec, but I will take the advice and redo with dict. Thanks for everyones assistance!

Comment: @Sav I'm not sure if a dictionary is what you need, since I have no idea what you're trying to do. Let's look at it in a different way, what are going to use these lists for? What is your broader goal?

Comment: @AMC (Thanks for taking the time to help me btw) 
I am running an experiment that outputs n-number of files. I flatten/do stuff to them and get each of them into an array E1 = [....] E2 = [...] for n-number of E's. All I wanna do is add E1 + E2 + ... + E_n to get E_total. My problem is that there are ALOT of E's which is why I tried to make the for loop so I could call a big array of E's (called arraylist) so I could just np.add.reduce the whole arraylist and find E_total. My end result is an E_total array which is just as long as E_n array, made up of summing E_1...E_n element by element.

Comment: @Sav You should share that code in your post, it's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @Sav take a look at my edit.  It should give you some idea of how to restructure your code.   You can do this all in a single loop and just build the 2D E array directly (which you can then call np.add.reduce on).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a multidimensional NumPy array. It still isn't clear to me why you want to do this, or what exactly your input looks like, but I thought it best to share an actual solution.

```py
import numpy as np

E1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
E2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
E3 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

two_dim_list = [E1, E2, E3]

print(two_dim_list)

arr = np.array(two_dim_list)

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
[[1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 5]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Comment: What I would like to add to this is how to append E1,E2,...E_n to two_dim_list. When I use ".append"  it messes me up since it only works with lists (I think?)